Influence of Yield on the Cheapest-To-Deliver bond to honour a short position on a treasury bond futures contract?
In Options, Futures and Other Derivatives 11e by John C. Hull section 6.2 in the subsection 'Cheapest-to-Deliver Bond', the author claims that:

A number of factors determine the cheapest-to-deliver bond. When bond yields are in
excess of 6%, the conversion factor system tends to favor the delivery of low-coupon
long-maturity bonds. When yields are less than 6%, the system tends to favor the
delivery of high-coupon short-maturity bonds. Also, when the yield curve is upwardsloping, there is a tendency for bonds with a long time to maturity to be favored,
whereas when it is downward-sloping, there is a tendency for bonds with a short time to
maturity to be delivered

How do we prove these claims rigorously?
My Approach
In order to prove the first claim, we consider two bonds with the same yield semi-annual $y > 3\%$ (or annual yield $>6\%$). For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that they have equal market/quoted prices. Let us assume that they have semi-annual coupon payments of $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1 > c_2$ and number of coupon payments $k_1$ and $k_2$. We need to prove that the second bond is cheaper to deliver than the first one, or equivalently, the conversion factor for the first bond ($CF_1$) is greater than the second bond ($CF_2$). For the sake of simplicity, we ignore accrual and assume coupons are 6 months away.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k_1} \frac{c_1}{(1+y)^i} + \frac{P}{(1+y)^{k_1}} = \sum_{i=1}^{k_2} \frac{c_2}{(1+y)^i} + \frac{P}{(1+y)^{k_2}} \tag{Assumption on market value}
$$
From the above equation, it can be proved easily $k_1 < k_2$
$$
CF_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{k_1} + \frac{c_1}{(1+3\%)^i} + \frac{P}{(1+3\%)^{k_1}} \tag{1}
$$
$$
CF_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k_2} + \frac{c_2}{(1+3\%)^i} + \frac{P}{(1+3\%)^{k_2}} \tag{2}
$$
I try to prove that $CF_1-CF_2 < 0$, so I subtract equation 2 from equation 1. Then, I substitute $c_1$ in terms of $c_2$ from the assumption.
However, the algebra gets too complicated. Is there any simpler algebraic argument to prove the two claims given in the book?
Besides mathematical proof, I find it hard to believe even intuitively. Is there some argument which can be given to convince myself at least intuitively that the statements are true?

There is some overlap between this qurstions and https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80173/bond-futures-why-ctd-driven-by-yields/80176#80176
